# How can I print adress labels

Tags: macbook-pro, printing, template

Is there a program to create address labels on my MacBook Pro laptop?  I want to do Christmas labels on the Avery Labels.

Comment: what productivity programs do you have on your computer? Word, Pages, Excel, Numbers etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use Word for Mac, an Excel spreadsheet, and an Avery template to do a labels mail merge on Mac.